# Windows Phone Emulator issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1.1

I'm developing a windows phone application on Visual Studio 2010, Windows 8 x86. I've setup Visual Studio to Run as an administrator. Every time I try to run the windows phone 7 application, i have also updated sdk 7.1.1 but it still  gives me this error:

Windows Phone: Deployment of application to device failed. Exception from HRESULT: 0x89721800

is there any solution regarding this?

Comment: Did you download and install latest version of games for Windows-Live then repair SDK installation before installing SDK 7.1.1 ?; this is the best way to get the setup right and bypass compatability issues  windows phone sdk 7.1 & 7.1.1 have with windows 8 : see this blog entry ffor detailed steps:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2012/02/29/10274694.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Start from [here](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us)! And you understand all.

for [wp7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570)

```
System requirements
Supported operating systems: Windows 7, Windows Vista

Windows® Vista® (x86 and x64) with Service Pack 2 – all editions except Starter Edition
Windows 7 (x86 and x64) – all editions except Starter Edition
Installation requires 4 GB of free disk space on the system drive.
3 GB RAM
Windows Phone Emulator requires a DirectX 10 or above capable graphics card with a WDDM 1.1 driver

The Windows Phone SDK 7.1 is compatible with the final version of Visual Studio 2010 SP1.
```

for [wp8](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471)

```
System requirements
Supported operating systems: Windows 8, Windows 8 Pro

Operating system type:
Windows 8 64-bit (x64) client versions
Hardware:
6.5 GB of free hard disk space
4 GB RAM
64-bit (x64) CPU
Windows Phone 8 Emulator:
Windows 8 Pro edition or greater
Requires a processor that supports Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)
If your computer meets the hardware and operating system requirements, but does not meet the requirements for the Windows Phone 8 Emulator, the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 will install and run. However, the Windows Phone 8 Emulator will not function and you will not be able to deploy or test apps on the Windows Phone 8 Emulator.
```

Basically, you need Win 8 64x or Win7.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio datastore is corrupted.

Try:

1. Close all Visual Studio instances that may be currently running.
2. Delete the folder “%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Phone Tools\CoreCon\10.0”
3. Launch a new instance of Visual Studio

More workarounds at reference link.

Reference: [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wptools/thread/796ea925-c1bf-4fb3-bc67-4967823b51eb)